# PHP: mysqli_fetch_assoc doesn't work with stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a **table** 'account' (id, email, pass) in MySQL database.

I have **stored procedure**:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `LoadAccount`(email_p VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT pass FROM account WHERE email = email_p;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And here's the **code**:

```
function loadAccount($email, $pass)
{
  // connect to DB
  // ...
  $query = "CALL LoadAccount('{$email}')";

  if ($mysqli->multi_query($query))
  {
    do
    {
      if ($result = $mysqli->store_result())
      {
        // Numbered array.
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
          printf("%s %s\n", $row[0]);
        }

        // Associative array.
//        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
//        {
//          printf("%s\n", $row['pass']);
//        }
        $result->free();
      }
      $mysqli->more_results();
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
  }
}
```

So, Numbered array section works, but if I comment it out and uncomment Associative array section — the page just hangs and loses connection.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: you are right to be puzzled because this is code that should work. Could you look at the mysql server log and also the slow query log (if it's enabled) and see what shows up

Comment: Server log shows error:
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.2.14.0, time stamp: 0x4ad08a08   
Faulting module name: php_mysqli.dll, version: 5.2.5.5, time stamp: 0x47389d89   
Exception code: 0xc0000005   
Fault offset: 0x0000000000002474   
Faulting process id: 0x1014   
Faulting application start time: 0x01cabb38919dc683   
Faulting application path: C:\apache64\bin\httpd.exe   
Faulting module path: C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll   
Report Id: 64124eed-2731-11df-9c2d-002564f16a19   

How do I enable query log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for weird things like that reinstalling of PHP helps! At least it did this time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the typo is in your code or not but:

```
printf("%s\n", $row[pass]);
```

should be:

```
printf("%s\n", $row['pass']);
```

Comment: No, that's not it. It hangs even if I do nothing inside the loop. You're right about missing quotes though.